# Spring Boot and properties data from Yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot

My Spring boot app is failing to create a bean with the properties object from the application.yml.

Here is what I did:

```
application.yml:

statsd:
   host: 10.0.5.23
   port: 8125
```

I created a `StatsdProperties @Component`class to hold the above data:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="statsd")
public class StatsdProperties {
   private String host;
   private int port;

   .... getters & setters
}
```

And I created another `@Component` class that should use the above properties:

```
 @Component
 public class MyClass{

   @Autowired
   private StatsdProperties statsdProperties;


   public MyClass(){
      statsdProperties.getPort()  <---  statsdProperties is null here
   }
```

And `statsdProperties` is null in the `MyClass`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: annotate the fields with `@Value` like `@Value("${host}")`

Comment: Looks like StatsdProperties is not being scanned and Bean is not actually created. Try the same with @Bean pattern.

Comment: #shahaf after adding the `@Value...` I got this error: `BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statsdProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'host' in value "${host}"`

Comment: @riorio silly question... is your class annotated with `@Configuration` ? you can use `@value` or `@ConfigurationProperties` but no need to do both unless you are using different fields name than the configuration

Answer (score 1):

Update your configuration file to this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties()
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "statsd")
public class StatsdProperties  {
  private String host;
  private int port;

  .... getters & setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable configuration in your `MyClass`:

```
 @Component
 @EnableConfigurationProperties(StatsdProperties.class)
 public class MyClass
```

Comment: That didn't change the null situation

Comment: What's your properties path? Can you share it

Comment: Other Spring properties from the yml are read correctly by the app. E.g. spring:
    jpa:
        database: MYSQL

Comment: Try to replace your `@Component` with `@Configuration` in `MyClass`

Comment: StatsdProperties does not need to be annotated with `@Component`